# How to implement different screens with HTML5

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have worked with HTML5 to create a small game with a single screen. This time I am trying to make one with multiple screens, eg a menu, the game, a results screen. I am not sure how to implement this.

The game is a quiz, and depending on the question some of the quizzes screens may have to display text, audio or videos (not hardcoded, they are from a database). For this reason I am worried about stability. How do I go about implementing these screens in HTML5 and how to do so in a way that will make my game stable?

I have included a screenflow diagram to give an idea of what screens I am implementing.

[image]

Comment: We gladly help you out with specific problems, so give it a try and if you get stuck post a new question here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for my games I use a "state" system. Consider each screen as a state:

- state "loading"
- state "student mau"
- state "enrol"
- state "view your quizz"
- state "attempt"
- state "answer"
  It's just an enum.

Actually, a state is not only a screen but can be several screens (like for the "play game" state which contains a "click to play" sub-state, a "playing" sub-state and a "you loose/win" substate.

Each state is a class with its properties, methods, sprites, ...
Each state encapsulate "setImage", "render", "processKeyboard", ... methods.

The main class of the app handles all the events (keyboards, mouse, display, spritesheet loading) and dispatch them to the current state. If you want to change the current state, call the "setCurrentState" of the main class.

Well, the main class is the center point of the application and every state is just as  a plugin. This way it's easy to add new state.

To get a perfect template, you also need a workflow engine, but this is more adapted for big games... You probaly don't need such a big feature in your app.

For canvas it's perfect. 
The loading state is the default one. It renders a "loading" text while the main class is loading the spritesheets images. When all images are loaded, the main class swith to the "home page" state. 
The "home page" state has its own method, buttons, ...

You can have a look at a example using cgSceneGraph (but the design should be the same for every development, with or without framework) : http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/examples/05_Game_CatchTheFlowers/js/class.main.js
(link to the example [here](http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/examples.html), chose "Game : Catch them all").
The code for a template peoject (used for the previous game) can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/GwennaelBuchet/cgSceneGraph/tree/master/examples/TEMPLATE_GAME) : https://github.com/GwennaelBuchet/cgSceneGraph/tree/master/examples/TEMPLATE_GAME

Feel free to ask more details about the implementation; I'll be glad to help :)

Comment: Wow, great explanation and thanks very much for the example! It seems like a great way to implement, I will give this a try.